# No write permissions for bootable usb

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, chmod, bootable

Background: I'm installing Windows for the DOS laptop for the first time, I've never done it before. There is a second laptop with Ubuntu 16. I downloaded the image from the official site, created a bootable USB flash drive through BalenaEtcher. But now I need to additionally upload drivers to this bootable usb (I looked here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28f8T4R6OWw, minute 4:17).

The problem is that I can't do it, because now there is no write access to this bootable flash drive. I tried a lot of things, `sudo chmod` command did not work.

Disk USB /dev/sdb

I hope you can help me, I'm really exhausted

Thanks a lot in advance

```
(base) loweis@loweis:~$ cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   devpts
    ext3
    ext2
    ext4
    squashfs
nodev   hugetlbfs
    vfat
nodev   ecryptfs
    fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
nodev   pstore
nodev   efivarfs
nodev   mqueue
nodev   autofs
nodev   binfmt_misc
nodev   overlayfs
nodev   overlay
nodev   aufs
    udf
```

Comment: Disk formatted ntfs? Reformat fat32?

Comment: Disk formatted fat32

Comment: `cat /proc/filesystems` shows vfat?

Comment: I've added picture in description, yes it shows

Comment: OK, changed it to output, thanks